# Pegar um atributo de outra classe e colocar como parâmetro em um construtor

Tags: java

Estou com uma duvida tremenda na qual não consigo achar um solução!

Estou tentando fazer que um construtor consiga pegar um atributo de uma classe e faça ele como parâmetro como mostra o código a seguir:

```
public class Comprador { 

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private EnderecoResidencial endereco;


    public Comprador(String nome, int idade, EnderecoResidencial endereco) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public Comprador(String nome, int idade) {
        this.setNome(nome);
        this.setIdade(idade);   
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public EnderecoResidencial getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(EnderecoResidencial endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public void imprime() {

        System.out.println("Nome: " + getNome());
        System.out.println("Idade: " + getIdade());
        System.out.println("Endereço: " + getEndereco());

    }

}
```

```
public class EnderecoResidencial {

    private String enderecoCompleto;

    public EnderecoResidencial(String endereco) {
        this.enderecoCompleto = endereco;
    }

    public String getEnderecoCompleto() {
        return enderecoCompleto;
    }

    public void setEnderecoCompleto(String enderecoCompleto) {
        this.enderecoCompleto = enderecoCompleto;
    }

    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println("O endereço completo é: " + getEnderecoCompleto());

    }
```

O problema é que ao fazer isso no main está gerando o erro: (The constructor Comprador(String, int, String) is  undefined.) Somente no construtor no qual eu quero pegar o endereço.

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EnderecoResidencial enderecoresidencial = new EnderecoResidencial("Rua Pauliceia");
        enderecoresidencial.imprime();

        Comprador comprador1 = new Comprador("Ari", 22, ""); //(The constructor Comprador(String, int, String) is  undefined.)
        comprador1.imprime();

        Comprador comprador2 = new Comprador("Ana", 18);
        comprador2.imprime();

        System.out.println(comprador1.getEndereco());

        System.out.println(enderecoresidencial.getEnderecoCompleto());  
    }

}
```

No que estou errado nesse código? O parâmetro do endereço no construtor está errado?

Answer (score 1):

Tá dando erro porque você está mandando uma string como parâmetro ao invés do objeto. Tente:

```
Comprador comprador1 = new Comprador("Ari", 22, enderecoresidencial);
```